# I only care about whether some specific tags exist in XML files and cares nothing about other tags. how should I compose xml schema file?

Tags: xml, xsd

for example, I only care about whether some necessary child tags, for example "name","sex", exist in the parent tag "person". And the apperance order of these "necessary" tags are not fixed(but the names of these tags are fixed).

this is OK.

```
<person>
    <name>peter</name>
    <sex>male</sex>
</person>
```

this also is OK. although the postions are changed

```
<person>
    <sex>male</sex>
    <name>peter</name>
</person>
```

this is also OK.(age,addr are unnecessary, and are allowed to be anywhere within person)

```
<person>
    <name>peter</name>
    <age>23</age>
    <addr>abc</addr>
    <sex>male</sex>
</person>
```

and this is no good because one of the necessary tag "name" doesn't exist.

```
<person>
    <age>23</age>
    <sex>male</sex>
</person>
```

can you tell me how to compose xml schema to check this?
the `<xsd:sequence>` ... seems not suitalbe for this situation.

addition:
In fact, besides the tag "name","sex", there are many(below 20) other "necessary" tags within the parent tag "person".

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to achieve this content model if the name element must come first: you define a sequence consisting of an element particle matching name, then an (optional, repeatable) wildcard particle (xs:any) matching anything.

It's harder to achieve it if the name element can come anywhere; the problem is that in XSD 1.0 the content model ends up ambiguous, because when you encounter the name element, it matches both the specific element particle for name, and the wildcard. XSD 1.1 solves this neatly by allowing this ambiguity: the element will match the specific particle in preference to the wild card. So in XSD 1.1 you can write

```
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xs:element name="name"/>
  <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

There's possibly another approach that would work: make the content model completely open, but define a uniqueness constraint that "name" must be unique. This implies that name must exist.

Comment: Dear Michael Kay, thank you for your reply. your solution resolved "half" of my problem. In fact, besides the "name" tag, I also have many(below 20) other "necessary" tags and the apperance order of this "necessary" tags cannot be limited, that means instead of "xs:sequence", I have to use "xs:all", but it seems that "xs:any" cannot be used within "xs:all". can you give me some suggestons about this. and can you give a sample of "completely open content model plus uniquesness contraint"? thanks again.

Comment: You have to make sure your XML processor is capable of supporting XML Schema 1.1 though, not all application servers support that level.

Answer (score 0):

Probably want something like:

```
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
```

inside your complex type specification.  So something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="person">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
              <xs:any minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The first two examples pass, but the third fails.

Comment: Dear Bert Evans, Thank you for your reply. The "other tags" is not limited to "age", in fact, I even don't know what the tags' name will be, so it's impossible to list all the "other tags"

Comment: @user1067607 Then you will want to use xs:any.  I added it in the code example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence then xsd:any

```
<xsd:element name="person">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Unfortunately you must start with a "name" element.

Comment: dear Archimedes Trajano
thank you for your reply. the actual problem is a little more complex since the "name" element will not always be the first element and there are other necessary elements besides "name".

Comment: The other way I can think of, but will also provide constraints is the xsd:unique element.  That will allow you to check via XPath on an element, BUT it checks for uniqueness.

Comment: Another way I can think of but also not verified is to create an element group that would list your permutations.  However, I can't really think on how that would look like at the moment.

Comment: However, if you need it to be that lax, you really should just do it in the application code.  It is much easier there, you can still allow anything under person using the technique given above (minus the name element).  There's nothing wrong with moving application specific logic into the application, in JEE there's no one tool for everything (and anyone that claims to be can be easily disproven).